# Bot not responding to prefix

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Okay, so I've just decided to make a whole new bot. The last one was buggy and a lot of features didn't work. I've decided that I'd write it smarter, but that hasn't worked out all too well so far. I couldn't even get past my first command :(

So I have this for  the code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = "<my token>"

const prefix = 'cb!';

bot.on('message', message => {

    let msg = message.content.toUpperCase();
    let sender = message.author;
    let cont = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(" ");
    let args = cont.slice(1);
// Commands
    // Ping
    if (msg === prefix + 'PING') {
         message.channel.send('Ping!');
    }

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`running`)

});


bot.login(token);
```

My commands don't work with `prefix + "ping"` or `prefix + purge`. 
My prefix being defined with `const cb! = prefix`. I also have tried `let prefix = cb!`

If I were to make the code for ping be: `if (msg === 'PING'` it would work. So I know the bot is working, it's just not responding to `prefix + 'PING'`, or at least I think.
So what should I do?

As always, thanks for taking time for reading this message.

Comment: prefix+'PING' is cb!PING, are you sure you're handling spaces?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by handling spaces, but what I'd want to happen is for me to send "cb!ping" and the bot respond with "Pong!" I believe the ```let msg = message.content.toUpperCase``` line fixes the all caps PING if that was what you meant.

Comment: Ah I see. How would I be able to keep the spaces? Or would I be able to?

Answer (score 0):

When someone write the message (for example cb!ping) the node save it into the variable and change this to upper case. Then node compare the variable with `prefix + 'PING'` and at finnally we get `CB!PING == cb!PING`, that returns `false`, so change `let msg = message.content.toUpperCase();` to `let msg = message.content.toLowerCase();`. Example:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = "<my token>"

const prefix = 'cb!';

bot.on('message', message => {

    let msg = message.content.toLowerCase();
    let sender = message.author;
    let cont = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(" ");
    let args = cont.slice(1);
// Commands
    // Ping
    if (msg === prefix + 'PING') {
         message.channel.send('Ping!');
    }

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`running`)

});


bot.login(token);
```

Comment: Has the same problem of no response.

Answer (score 0):

**Convert both sides of `===` to the same case**

You're misshandling `.toUpperCase()` and `.toLowerCase()`.

If you want to compare string in case-insensitive way, you'll have to convert both sides of `===` to either lower case or uppercase

```js
// lowercase
if (msg.toLowerCase() === (prefix + "ping").toLowerCase()) {
  /* do stuff */
};

// UPPERCASE
if (msg.toUpperCase() === (prefix + "ping").toUpperCase()) {
  /* do stuff */
};
```

Notes:

- Whichever you pick, stay consistent with that decision so that this doesn't happen anymore.
- You could also just be consistent when declaring variables. If you're going to use upper case then you should declare your variales as upper case `const prefix = "CB!";`